# dealing cards to players and updating dictionary with player:hand

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random

I am trying to create a deck of cards, randomly shuffle it, and deal 3 cards to 3 players. I created a function buildDeck() that returns the 48 needed cards in deck as a list. I then tried to make a dictionary playerHands with key, value {playername: [3 random cards from deck]}. I then def pullCards() which shuffles the deck, checks that there are atleast 9 cards in the deck, and then draws 3 random cards from the deck and removing them using pop(). I would now like to assign the 3 randomly drawn cards as a value for each player key in the dict playerHand.

I am new to programming and don't really know if this was a good setup for this program nor do I know if this use of list in lists and dictionaries are appropriate for this.

I am not supposed to use classes for this program and I also don't even know how! Really would appreciate some help! Thanks

```
import random

def printMenu():
    #prints menu of options
    menu = "s: start new game\np: Pull cards for all players\no: output deck\nh: output players’ hand\ne: exchange one card\nd: declare winner\nq: quit\nSelect an option:\n"
    print(menu)
    return
printMenu()

def buildDeck():
    suits = ['Clubs', 'Golds', 'Cups', 'Swords']
    values = list(range(1, 13))
    deck = []
    #iterates through elements in suits and elements in values appending each respective element as a new element into deck
    for i in suits:
        for x in values:
            deck.append(list([i, x]))
    return deck


def startNewGame():
    #prompts user for player names
    player1 = input("Enter player 1's name:\n")
    player2 = input("Enter player 2's name:\n")
    player3 = input("Enter player 3's name:\n")
    
    #calls 48 card deck using buildDeck() function 
    buildDeck()
    
    #creates dictionary of each player's empty hand with values of None
    playerHand = {player: None for player in [player1, player2, player3]}
    return playerHand

    
def pullCards():
    playerHand = startNewGame()
    deck = buildDeck()
    #randomly shuffles deck
    random.shuffle(deck)
    #iterates through cards in the deck and checks if at least 9 cards
    for cards in deck:
        if deck.count(cards) >= 9:
            #draws 3 random cards and pop() removes cards from the deck
            for i in range(3):
                randomCard = deck.pop(random.randint(0, len(deck) - 1))
                for keys in playerHand.keys():
                    playerHand[keys] = randomCard
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Along with answering your question, allow me to give you some tips.

1. Don't make printMenu a function if you only need to do it once. Even if you need to use it multiple times, menu can be defined outside the function unless you need to redefine it every time the function is called.
2. In buildDeck, suits and decks can be written outside the function, like with menu.
   `deck.append(list([i, x]))` can be written as `deck.append([i, x])` because [i,x] is already a list.
3. In StartNewGame, calling BuildDeck does nothing, since the deck it makes isn't assigned to anything, and you're using BuildDeck again later anyways. Sean C's advice is true too - use [] instead of None, and simply append later on.
4. In PullCards, no need to use random.shuffle, since you're using randint later, unless you have to print the deck sometime. Even then, you can remove the randint later - keep one of the two.
   Now for the loop in PullCards.

```
for cards in deck:
        if deck.count(cards) >= 9:
            #draws 3 random cards and pop() removes cards from the deck
            for i in range(3):
                randomCard = deck.pop(random.randint(0, len(deck) - 1))
                for keys in playerHand.keys():
                    playerHand[keys] = randomCard
```

was your original code.
One problem here is that due to `for cards in deck:`, this bit of code will run 48 times. I don't think you meant to do that, and you can safely remove the for loop and one indentation level.
Another one is that this code selects a random card, and gives the same one to all 3 players. The last is that because of `playerHand[keys] = randomCard`, the third randomCard is the value assigned to each player key in the dictionary. What you want is a list as the value of each player key, each list having 3 cards.

To fix both of these, first we move `randomCard = deck.pop(random.randint(0, len(deck) - 1))` into the second for loop.
From this:

```
for i in range(3):
    randomCard = deck.pop(random.randint(0, len(deck) - 1))
    for keys in playerHand.keys():
        playerHand[keys] = randomCard
```

to this:

```
for i in range(3):
    for keys in playerHand.keys():
        randomCard = deck.pop(random.randint(0, len(deck) - 1))
        playerHand[keys] = randomCard
```

And change `playerHand[keys] = randomCard` to `playerHand[keys].append(randomCard)`, like Sean C suggested, so that each player key's value, which we changed to an empty list earlier, gets 3 cards appended to it (ie those cards, those [i,x] lists, are now elements of this list).

Hope this helped.

Comment: For that, perhaps you should define deck outside pullCards, and write `global deck` in pullCards instead. See, there's something called 'scope' in Python (and other languages) which means that variables defined in a function can't be used outside it, and variables defined in the program can't be changed by functions by default. However, if you write `global deck` that makes python recognise that the global variable deck will be used and changed whenever this function is called. Plus now you can use deck outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

> I would now like to assign the 3 randomly drawn cards as a value for each player key in the dict playerHand

I changed `playerHand = {player: None` to `playerHand = {player: []` in startNewGame so that you can append cards into the list in pullCards, then sorted the latter's logic so you end up with 3 cards in each player's hand. I'm not sure if the test for deck length is in the right place for you - move it around if not (len(deck) if fine - couldn't see what you wanted to do by iterating through it).  It runs fine here - hope it helps.

```
def startNewGame():
    #prompts user for player names
    player1 = input("Enter player 1's name:\n")
    player2 = input("Enter player 2's name:\n")
    player3 = input("Enter player 3's name:\n")
    
    #calls 48 card deck using buildDeck() function 
    buildDeck()
    
    #creates dictionary of each player's empty hand with values of None
    playerHand = {player: [] for player in [player1, player2, player3]}
    return playerHand

    
def pullCards():
    playerHand = startNewGame()
    deck = buildDeck()
    #randomly shuffles deck
    random.shuffle(deck)
    #checks if at least 9 cards
    #draws 3 random cards and pop() removes cards from the deck
    for player in playerHand: # 'for' iterates through the dict's keys
        for i in range(3):
            if len(deck) >= 9:
                randomCard = deck.pop(random.randint(0, len(deck) - 1))
                playerHand[player].append(randomCard)
    
    print(playerHand)

pullCards()
```

gives

```
{'w': [['Clubs', 6], ['Golds', 10], ['Cups', 6]], 'e': [['Clubs', 7], ['Golds', 7], ['Golds', 1]], 'r': [['Golds', 12], ['Clubs', 12], ['Cups', 4]]}
```

Also, just seen `buildDeck()` runs twice and does nothing in startNewGame - remove it from there or assign it to a var and pass it to pullCards

Comment: @angus-watters  just declare `global deck` at the top of `buildDeck()` and deck will be in the global namespace for everything - unless you try to re-assign it in a function when it will silently become a local var to that func and have no effect on the global var of the same name

Comment: @ang-wg2 learn about string.join() - this should set you right, about halfway down the page https://realpython.com/python-string-split-concatenate-join/  . Note that once you've joined all the 'card' lists in the hand list, you will then have a list of strings, which you can .joun again to make one big, non-list string. If you use '\n' to join, each card will be on a newline.